# jquery click on div to set cursor in child input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have no idea if this is even possible.

For styling purposes, I have a div with an input field in it. I want to put the cursor (the blinking **|**) on the input field (basically allow the user to start their input) once they click the surrounding div of the input field.

This image might explain my problem better. I colored the inputfield blue to better illustrate the issue:

[image: my input type issue]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with jQuery:

```js
$(".area").click(function() {
  $(this).find("input,textarea").focus();
});
```

```css
.area {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

However you might not need jQuery. You can use `label` tag and its standard behaviour:

```css
.area {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="area" for="name">
  <input type="text" id="name">
</label>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I could not make it work. How many elements can I potentially add in a label?

Comment: @Spyron10 For each input you need to have a seperate label.

Comment: I should have been clearer, what I meant was can I put an <i> tag and an input element in the same label?

Comment: @Spyron10 Yes, you can

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JQuery just use a simple .focus()  Here is a link to the documentation https://api.jquery.com/focus/

If you put this in your load function it will automatically put the cursor in the input box.  I would recommend using an actual ID though.

```
$( "input" ).focus();
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. They specifically wanted to focus the nearest input, when clicking in the grey area.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie This is indeed an incomplete answer, however I think it works if I add a .click function to the parent div, and then have it find the textarea/input and then focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any Javascript you have another option ... that comes with the HTML:

```
<label for="inputOne"></label>
```

Style it with the background, position it underneath the input and if the user clicks the label they focus the input inside the `for` attribute

Comment: I did try the label, but I could not make it work, because I didn't know I had to position it underneath the input. Doesn't that kind of defeat it's purpose, though?

Comment: As you can see in @TimOsadchiy answer it works. The label is also good to add to the forms because it increases the accessibility of your website.. something that most people usually forget of.